# Editing questions for spelling/grammar reasons

Tags: discussion, editing

Is this a valid reason for editing? I'm not talking the extreme of:

> hi i wnt 2 mk a gaem bt i dnt no how...

but since we do have a lot of non english native speaking people here, sometimes grammar and spelling does cause something of an issue when trying to fully understand what's being asked.

(Was not sure which mandatory tag to add)

Answer (score 7):

Yes you should edit early and often. Most visitors come from google and having a clean question means the site seems more respectable.

Comment: Too bad now there are only 10 users and moderators able to edit peoples posts.  Rep requirements have converted to SO like requirements.